# obtainMessage arguments meaning

Tags: android, methods, arguments, message

I'm trying to understand this piece of code:

```
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

and the only thing, totally obscure for me is `obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)`, which corresponds to the next declaration:

```
public final Message obtainMessage (int what, int arg1, int arg2, Object obj)

Added in API level 1
Same as obtainMessage(), except that it also sets the what, obj, arg1,and arg2 values on the returned Message.

Parameters
what    Value to assign to the returned Message.what field.
arg1    Value to assign to the returned Message.arg1 field.
arg2    Value to assign to the returned Message.arg2 field.
obj     Value to assign to the returned Message.obj field.
```

So please, could someone explain to me what these parameters are and what they serve for?

P.S.: MESSAGE_READ is undefined in that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mHandler.obtainMessage():
```

By using this method we allow Android to take care of pooling Message objects, which helps to keep object allocation down, especially if you are creating messages frequently, such as using handlers for animations.

**what:**   User-defined message code so that the recipient can identify what this message is about.

**obj** An arbitrary object to send to the recipient.

**arg1 and arg2** are lower-cost alternatives to using setData() if you only need to store a few integer values.

Comment: and what if i want to store more integers

Answer (score 0):

They're all defined by you.  What is an id.  Its generally either an enum or a constant defined in the class that owns the handler you post it to.  It should define the type of message, assuming there's more than one message to be sent.  arg1, arg2, and obj are all values sent with the message in case you need to pass it data.  They can hold whatever values you want, or none at all.